# Adding JavaScript Code to A Single Page in Joomla (Google Remarketing Code)

Tags: javascript, joomla

I would like to add the Google Remarketing JavaScript code to my site. According to Google's documentation, I need to add the code right before the  tag in my HTML document. I can easily do this in the template which would add the code to all of my pages. But what if I only want to add the JavaScript code to a single page? What is the best method to go about doing this?

I tried assigning a new module position right before the  tag and inserting the code using a custom HTML module. Only problem is, it wrapped the code in a  meaning the remarketing code wasn't truly inserted right above the  tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a module which allows to run custom code in it. There are several solutions to this in the JED: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules

Answer (score 0):

You could go about this by using `JFactory::addScriptDeclaration();`. More info can be found about this via the following link:

http://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/addScriptDeclaration

Or, you could try using [Google Tag Manager](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/analytics/content-statistics/22448) which is a Plugin for Joomla 2.5 and 3.x